# Postgresql - issue with INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, case

I have the following SQL:

```
drop table if exists core.fact_request_tickets;

create table core.fact_request_tickets (
    id                                  serial4 primary key,
    ticket_no                           text not null,
    title                               text not null,
    sender_id                           int4 not null,
    request                             text not null,
    status_id                           int4 not null,
    is_latest                           boolean null,
    group_id                            int4 not null,
    size_id                             int4 not null,
    business_partner_team_project_id    int4 not null,
    "log"                               text not null,
    rating_met_sla_id                   int4 not null,
    rating_communicated_id              int4 not null,
    rating_timely_id                    int4 not null,
    rating_self_sufficient_id           int4 not null,
    rating_complete_and_accurate_id     int4 not null,
    log_date                            timestamptz not null,
    etl_batch_id                        int4 not null
);
with finalTable as (
    select      rts.ticket_no
                , rts.title
                , rts.sender_id
                , rts.request
                , rts.status_id
                , (case when ls.last_log_date is null then false else true end) as is_latest
                , rts.group_id
                , rts.size_id
                , rts.business_partner_team_project_id
                , rts."log"
                , rts.rating_met_sla_id
                , rts.rating_communicated_id
                , rts.rating_timely_id
                , rts.rating_self_sufficient_id
                , rts.rating_complete_and_accurate_id
                , rts.log_date
                , rts.etl_batch_id
    from        requestTickets rts 
    left join   lastStatus ls on rts.log_date = ls.last_log_date
)


insert into core.fact_request_tickets
(   ticket_no
    , title
    , sender_id
    , request
    , status_id
    , is_latest
    , group_id
    , size_id
    , business_partner_team_project_id
    , "log"
    , rating_met_sla_id
    , rating_communicated_id
    , rating_timely_id
    , rating_self_sufficient_id
    , rating_complete_and_accurate_id
    , log_date
    , etl_batch_id
)

select      ticket_no
            , title
            , sender_id
            , request
            , status_id
            , is_latest
            , group_id
            , size_id
            , business_partner_team_project_id
            , "log"
            , rating_met_sla_id
            , rating_communicated_id
            , rating_timely_id
            , rating_self_sufficient_id
            , rating_complete_and_accurate_id
            , log_date
            , etl_batch_id
from        finalTable


commit;
```

When I execute the following SQL:

```
select      ticket_no
            , title
            , sender_id
            , request
            , status_id
            , is_latest
            , group_id
            , size_id
            , business_partner_team_project_id
            , "log"
            , rating_met_sla_id
            , rating_communicated_id
            , rating_timely_id
            , rating_self_sufficient_id
            , rating_complete_and_accurate_id
            , log_date
            , etl_batch_id
from        finalTable
```

It returns data that I am expecting - specifically, there are records that have 'true' for the `is_latest` column.  However, when I execute the entire script, and then I query the `core.fact_request_tickets` table, all the values for the `is_latest` column show up as 'false'. It seems the `INSERT INTO` statement is causing the data inserted into the core.fact_request_tickets table to show up incorrectly (there should be some records with a `true` value for `is_latest`, but instead all values return as `false`); but when I run the query against `finalTable` separately, it returns the data I am expecting.

I'm not sure why this is happening - any ideas?

Comment: Please setup a fiddle and share the link to allow people to replicate your issue.

Comment: E.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/ can be used to do that.

Comment: Do you (also) have a table finalTable? Or just the cte using this name? If it’s just a cte, you couldn’t query the cte without the cte-syntax.

Comment: I solved the issue by using TEMP tables instead of the "with as" clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's got to be a syntax error in the script itself and unrelated to the "WITH AS" clause.

- Semicolons are needed after the entire INSERT statement and before COMMIT;
- COMMIT may not be supported in the batch environment you have (executing as OWNER context), rolling back any pending changes (so next select is looking at the old data).

I recommend sticking to a plain INSERT - SELECT statement (and testing that separately):

```
    insert into core.fact_request_tickets
    (   ticket_no
        , title
        , sender_id
        , request
        , status_id
        , is_latest
        , group_id
        , size_id
        , business_partner_team_project_id
        , "log"
        , rating_met_sla_id
        , rating_communicated_id
        , rating_timely_id
        , rating_self_sufficient_id
        , rating_complete_and_accurate_id
        , log_date
        , etl_batch_id
    ) select  rts.ticket_no
            , rts.title
            , rts.sender_id
            , rts.request
            , rts.status_id
            , (case when ls.last_log_date is null then false else true end) as is_latest
            , rts.group_id
            , rts.size_id
            , rts.business_partner_team_project_id
            , rts."log"
            , rts.rating_met_sla_id
            , rts.rating_communicated_id
            , rts.rating_timely_id
            , rts.rating_self_sufficient_id
            , rts.rating_complete_and_accurate_id
            , rts.log_date
            , rts.etl_batch_id
        from requestTickets rts 
        left outer join lastStatus ls
                        on rts.log_date = ls.last_log_date;
```

Also, if this is a one-time query, consider using temporary tables. Which saves you overhead of logging and saving results permanently. A permission to create them may need to be granted to the batch account.